# Textblob: filter words by tags

Tags: python, textblob

[I have added a picture of what the tagged data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsOuy.png)

I am trying to analyse text from a list of FB posts I have in dataframe format.

I have managed to extract noun_prases and tags with the following codes:

```
data_tags = data['text'].apply(lambda post: TextBlob(post).tags)
data_noun_phrases = data['text'].apply(lambda post: TextBlob(post).noun_phrases)
```

Now I need to:

1. Extract the most common nouns and adjectives
2. extract the most common noun_phrases.

Is there a way I can do this?